# gem rich don't apperas in Active_admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin, rich-text-editor

I installed gem rich in my Rails 4.1.5 project. I'm using Active Admin. In my file of admin I have this line that calls rich:

```
f.input :content, :as => :rich, :config => { :height => '200px' }, :label => 'Conteúdo'
```

But when I open Active_admin, the rich don't appears (should appear right below the first field):
[image]

My gemfile:
`gem 'rich', :git => 'https://github.com/kreativgebiet/rich.git'`

In my application.rb I have this lines:

```
config.assets.prefix = '/lince/assets'
config.relative_url_root = '/lince'
config.action_controller.relative_url_root = '/lince'
```

When I try without this lines, rich works fine.

Anyone can help me? I can't understand why this not working.

Thanks.

Comment: What gem did you install because I do not see a rich_editor gem anywhere

Comment: @engineersmnky I'm sorry, I update the question. The gem is rich.

Comment: did you restart your server after you installed it?

Comment: @engineersmnky Yes, a several times :/

Comment: @engineersmnky I think that I found the problem. I updated the question.

Comment: Did you make sure to follow this instruction as well *"Make sure you add `//= require rich` to your `app/assets/javascripts/active_admin.js`."*

Comment: @engineersmnky Yes. I found the problem now and add in the question, but I don't know how to resolve yet.

Answer (score 0):

rich has not been updated in years.  I recommend you look at other [WYSIWYG editors](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/wiki/Plugins#wysiwig-editor)

Comment: Which one do you recomend? Froala maybe?

Comment: I don't have hands on experience, you should ask blocknotes: he did four of these, all updated relatively recently.